# How to use Ionic super tabs in ionic 4?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, dependencies, ionic4

I work with `ionic 4` and I added `super tabs` in my app, and when I want to run my app this **error:**

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@ionic-super-tabs/angular/dist/fesm5.js
>       Module not found: Error: Can’t resolve ‘@ionic-super-tabs/core/dist/types/components’ in
>   ‘E:\Angular_Project\Ionic project\Clone
>   Raihan\raihan-4\node_modules@ionic-super-tabs\angular\dist’
>       [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

For ionic 4 an updated Packages published under the @ionic-super-tabs/ scope are compatible with ionic 4.0.0 and above to use it just run this:

```
npm i @ionic-super-tabs/angular
```

and for more information you can find it in this repository on github [ionic-super-tabs@ionic4](https://github.com/zyra/ionic-super-tabs#ionic-4)

Hope this will help you.